# Can't upload App - 'An error occurred uploading to the itunes store'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, submit, app-store-connect

I'm trying to upload my app to the store. This isn't the first time so I'm familiar with the process.

I've tried both through the Organizer (preferred method) and the Application Loader, but both offer vague error messages.

I've recently updated to Xcode 4 in an attempt to fix it. My archived project validates fine and everything, but shortly after hitting submit, I get an error saying:

An error occurred uploading to the itunes store

But no other info. So I really don't know what could be wrong. I've appealed to Apple but nothing yet.

What could be wrong?

**EDIT:**

I should probably mention that my project has 2 targets, but I have provisioning profiles for both, both for development and distribution, so can't see why this would be a problem. It's the only unusual thing about the project as far as I can tell. Still no word from Apple either...

Thanks!

Michael

Comment: Be patient & pray that apple's software development become user friendly; Good Luck!

Comment: iTunes is like that. Stick to simple sentence structure, avoid multisyllabic words, and for god's sake, please no metaphors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your Build Configuration for your Archive Scheme to Distribution or smth. like this.

For this, go to Product > Edit Scheme and on the left side you'll find the Archive-Scheme.

Check if you've added everything to your project like Entitlements, and wether you've added this to your configuration. Check also the Base SDK and the code signing options of your configuration. If you've done this, it should really work.

Answer (score 9):

For those of you that are having this issue with Xcode 4.3.2 and Java SE 6 1.6, try this:

```
cd /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions
sudo ln -s CurrentJDK /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5
sudo ln -s CurrentJDK /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0
```

It worked for me.

Comment: When you look at your versions, you'll only see 1.6 and 1.6.0 still running the sudo command will recreate 1.5 and will fix your problem: cd /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions
sudo ln -s CurrentJDK /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5
sudo ln -s CurrentJDK /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0

Answer (score 3):

A bit late, I know - but for anyone still having this problem - Look in your /var/log/system.log log file. In my case the problem was that the iTMSTransporter script (used by the Organizer when uploading the file) used 'awk', and I had to replace it with '/usr/bin/awk'.

Completely solved my problem.

Y.

Comment: please can you add more details what did you actually replace and with what ?

Comment: Solved my problem too, so I added step-by-step info in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've had trouble before where I had a quote `'` in my password. It would always fail to upload.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if anyone is having a similar problem, I seem to have fixed it.

Not *entirely* sure how, but I completely deleted xcode (from the terminal), reinstalled it, restarted my computer, and by some sort of black magic, it just started uploading.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and the solution was to update to java 1.6

I see this when I was looking in the console log to understand why Application Loader doesn't work.

Comment: 26/07/11 22:39:50 Application Loader[3257]  Error:
Java 1.5 or Java 1.6 is required. Currently, java is the default java version. Please upgrade.

Comment: I am getting the same error at the moment. Did you solve this problem? (There was a Java update today for OS X Lion 10.7.3.) I tried installing Application Loader and reinstalling XCode.

Comment: @BarumRho, see fix at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011635/an-error-occurred-uploading-to-the-itunes-store-please-upgrade-java

Answer (score 0):

I restarted my computer and it worked. Very wear problem. The other thing that I did, was to submit directly after archiving, instead of validiting first.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the proxy configured in Network Preferences was the reason. Without proxy it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I spent all morning trying to figure this out, so I thought I'd post what fixed my issue with app loader. I just downloaded the latest App Loader (2.5.1) from iTunes connect. The link is in the footer.