# An error occurred uploading to the iTunes store

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification, xcode4.3, itunes-store

Using Xcode 4.3.2.

Since yesterday, I can't upload to ITunes Store. I can't find any reasons.

Archive -> Validate... no problem.

But, it is occurred error  in distribute.

[image]

My app is using Push.

My Xcode version is 4.3.2.

What do I do to escape this state?

Please help me... and thank you.

Comment: You should contact Developer Support at apple and give them specific information about your issue and/or post in the appropriate Apple Developer Forum. This is not really a programming question, per-se.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had the similar issue..which i was able to fix using the solution mentioned here - [An error occurred uploading to the iTunes Store - Please upgrade Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011635/an-error-occurred-uploading-to-the-itunes-store-please-upgrade-java/10017638#comment12809592_10017638)

for quick reference I am adding the solution here also

open terminal window and execute below lines of code

```
cd /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions
sudo ln -s CurrentJDK /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5
sudo ln -s CurrentJDK /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0
```

Comment: What you put here didn't work for me and differs from what is at the link

Comment: Try to use "Software Update..." from "Apple symbol" also works

Answer (score 11):

I upgraded to java 1.7 (October 2012) and applied the latest Apple patch 2012-006 (if I'm not wrong)

Well, it disabled the java preferences (the Oracle Java pref is used inside the System Pref) and the Java Preferences in the Utilities folder was removed (by the latest Apple patch), because it seems they want yo force you to use the latest Java release (I can understand it, considering the security problems).

Result: I'm not able to submit to the app store and there is no way to re-enable it

XCode use Java at it's core function and a problem in Java makes Apple XCode unusable to submit to the App Store ... I didn't suspect that.

Comment: +1 for the explanation. I am facing the same problem, so whats the solution, have you found any ?

Answer (score 10):

Well I managed to workaround the issue by updating my symlinks. Here's what I did:

> cd /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions
>
> ls -l
>
> total 72
> lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   10 Oct 18 16:41 1.4 -> CurrentJDK
>
> lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   10 Oct 18 16:41 1.4.2 -> CurrentJDK
>
> lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   10 Oct 18 16:41 1.5 -> CurrentJDK
>
> lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   10 Oct 18 16:41 1.5.0 -> CurrentJDK
>
> lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   10 Oct 18 16:41 1.6 -> CurrentJDK
>
> lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   10 Oct 18 16:41 1.6.0 -> CurrentJDK
>
> drwxr-xr-x  8 root  wheel  272 Oct 18 16:42 A
>
> lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   10 Oct 18 17:18 Current -> A
>
> lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   59 Oct 18 16:41 CurrentJDK -> /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents
>
> sudo mv Current Current.bak
>
> sudo ln -s CurrentJDK Current
>
> java -version
>
> java version "1.6.0_37"
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_37-b06-434-11M3909)
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.12-b01-434, mixed mode)

This changes the 'Current' symlink to point to the same version that 'CurrentJDK' is pointing to. This may or may not be the same on your system, so double check. This may or may not cause other problems, but so far I haven't seen any.

To undo the changes, just go back to the same directory and:

> sudo rm Current
>
> sudo mv Current.bak Current

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great thanks ma.. I tried all other but none worked except these

Answer (score 3):

Try to use "Software Update..." from "Apple symbol" also works

Comment: Thanks! This is the best simple way! :-)

Answer (score 2):

If Xcode gives you the following error in Console

> Error: Java 1.5, 1.6, or 1.7 is required. Currently, java is the
>   default java version. Please upgrade.

Check whether there is a Software Update.
In my case there was one: Java for OSX 2012-002

> Java for OS X 2012-002 delivers improved compatibility, security, and
>   reliability by updating Java SE 6 to 1.6.0_31.
>
> Please quit any web browsers and Java applications before installing
>   this update.
>
> See http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5055 for more details about this
>   update.
>
> See http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1222 for information about the
>   security content of this update.

After the update I could submitted my app with no error.

Answer (score 1):

It's an issue with the last java version, a workaround in terminal write:

```
sudo ln -s CurrentJDK /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5
sudo ln -s CurrentJDK /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0
```

Then you can upload normally.

Answer (score 0):

This did not solve my problem. I was having this problema because I installed and set as default the Oracle Java 1.7. Disabling it and using Apple Java, this problem went away.

Comment: I had the same problem yesterday and setting turning off (uncheck) Java 1.7 in Application > Utilities > Java Preferences enabled me upload.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Java 1.7 Broke the Xcode Application uploader again!! I filed this as a Bug on ADC and it was acknowledged as such.

I was able to fix two ways:

1. Unistall Java 1.7 and fallback to Apple Java 1.6.34 or 35 work.
2. Temporarily turn off Java 1.7. Goto: Applications > Utilities > Java Preferences and un-check java 1.7. After that the uploader worked. If you need 1.7 you can turn it back on after you upload.