# Error in distribute with XCode 4.5.1

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6, xcode4.5

I installed xcode 4.5.1 for supporting iphone 5.
After creation of the archive, the validation of the app passes without error. but afterwards during distribution when uploading the app, the following error is shown:
The following issues were found during validation:
An error occurred uploading to the iTunes Store.

Uploading was possible with xcode 4.3.
In iTunesConnect I just see "Waiting for upload" but no error log. Is there a local error log that shows more details?
What could be the reason for the error?

Comment: 4.5.1 is out, maybe it was a bug that is fixed now.

Comment: Sorry, I was not precise enough. I am using already 4.5.1

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in [An error occurred uploading to the iTunes store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10022981/an-error-occurred-uploading-to-the-itunes-store)

The 4.5 apple uploader does not work with Oracle Java 1.7 but requires Apple Java 1.6

Answer (score 0):

Could be some local problem, Try to close everything (xcode&orginizer) and open up again. That should do the trick.