# iPhone - An error occurred uploading to the iTunes store?

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store

Hi I am stuck with submitting the app to iTunes Store. I am able to validate the ipa successfully, but when I submit the app to the iTunes store i am getting the error. I tried with both app loader and Xcode. I have contacted the apple support but no use. Here is the screen shot of the exact error, but i didn't get anything from this. 
[image: error log]

I am using Xcode 4.1, mac os version 10.6.8. I need the solution urgently. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Go to console of you mac, then see the errors. I think you may not install the java, please check. I receiving the same error. then i installed java, solved

Comment: I would check out the answers to this question. [Stack Overflow An Error Occurred Uploading to the iTunes Store](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011635/an-error-occurred-uploading-to-the-itunes-store-please-upgrade-java/10017638#comment12809592_10017638). The main discussion in this thread is that you need to upgrade your Java software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came accross same error with Xcode 4.5.0 on Mountain Lion. Problem was that current Java version was 1.7.x. What helped was temporarily removing current java version from /Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions

See [Xcode 4.5 iOS 6 error uploading to itunes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13092420/xcode-4-5-ios-6-error-uploading-to-itunes)