# Problems upload iOs App to App Store using both methods from XCode 5 - XCode Organizer and Application Loader

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, application-loader

Common question on SO but somehow despite following Apple's Guideline and following the guides for multiple questions on SO, I somehow couldn't get to resolve this issue and couldn't understand the error especially since I had my provisioning and code signing certificates sorted out.

So any help would be appreciated.

Steps I've done until now to resolve the error:

- Provisioning profiles have been downloaded and validated as per App Store Guidelines
- Code Signing Identities filled in the 'Build Settings' part of App Settings as shown in screenshot below
- Revoked and Create New Certificates from Apple Developer
- I had two accounts in my XCode 5 - Removed the Profile which I wasn't uploading the app to in order to reduce the possible conflicts.

[image: Screenshots from Build Settings of XCode 5 - Current Project]

[image: Account Preferences]

The following steps reproduce my error:

Error via Distribution using XCode Organizer : No identities are available for signing

- App archived successfully
- Click on 'Archive'
- 'No identities are available for signing shows up'
- Click on Download Identities > I choose my respective team
- XCode suddenly quits

Error via Application Loader:

- App Archived Successfully
- Click on 'Archive'
- Choose 'ad hoc or enterprise option'
- Choose Profile to Sign in with
- Choose the Team Provisioning Profile associated with Distribution and Development
- Load ipa into Application Loader
- Click on 'Send'
- Application Upload Process start
- Then I get 'ITMS-9000' error with the following message:

  ERROR: ERROR ITMS-9000: "Invalid Provisioning Profile. 
  The provisioning profile included in the bundle co.xxxxxxxxxxxx.Perinatologie             [Payload/Perinatologie.app] is invalid. 
  [Missing code-signing certificate.] 
  For more information, visit the iOS Developer Portal." atSoftwareAssets/SoftwareAsset (MZItmspSoftwareAssetPackage)

The following questions were my resources from SO:`

- [No identities are available for signing XCode 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746703/no-identities-are-available-for-signing-xcode-5)
- [No Identities are available for signign XCode 5 version 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592074/no-identities-are-available-for-signing)
- [Can't Upload app an error occurred uploading to the Itunes Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291039/cant-upload-app-an-error-occurred-uploading-to-the-itunes-store)

Comment: You need a store distribution provisioning profile, do you have that?

Comment: I think you have created your build with development provisioninng profile instead of distribution provisioning profile

Comment: In code signing, all of your options are pointing to iOS developer profile instead of distribution profile.

Comment: I downloaded the distribution provisioning profile before, did it again now and it worked like a charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Question resolved by redownloading an App Store Distribution Profile.

Thanks for the outside perspective. Sometimes being tired doesn't help at all.